# Is there an easy way to migrate a SharePoint Online Site to another tenant?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint Online **Communication site** that I'd like to migrate to another tenant.
Is there an easy way to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try to "Save site as template" feature on the feature, see this: https://expert-advice.org/office365/migrate-sharepoint-online-different-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365-tenants/. To migrate a SharePoint Online site collection, it is recommended to consider using third party migration tools.

Comment: Thank you, Allen, there are any 3rd migration tools recommended?

Comment: You can use Google to search related 3rd party tools and compare them or contact the 3rd part tool support for help.

Comment: I had tried several 3rd tools, It doesn't work. Thanks any way~